# Compare Two Associative Array with different value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two Associative array.

```
$a1 = array("Peter"=>"a","Ben"=>"b","Joe"=>"c");
$a2 = array("Peter"=>"5","Joe"=>"15");
```

and Out put result should be...

```
a=5
b=null
c=15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($a1 as $aKey => $aValue) {
    echo $aValue, '=';
    echo (isset($a2[$aKey])) ? $a2[$aKey] : 'null';
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: answer is looking correct as per `OP` requirement, in case `$a2` length more then `$a1` then `$a2` records would be skipped in comparison ??

Comment: OP hasn't given any indication of what they would expect to see for an entry that existed in $a2 but not in $a1... `null=20` perhaps?

Comment: in my case $a1 length always be greater than $a2.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($a1 as $key => $value) {
    echo $a1[$key].'='.$a2[$key];
}
```

You will get the output, but this have nothing to do with array comparing.